# Google Cloud Platform speech to text - customize transcribed text

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm using the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) [model adaptation feature of speech to text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation) to enable recognition of utterances that are unique to an industry, e.g. When a user utters JSON, it should be transcribed as JSON instead of 'Jason'. I achieve this by using a phrase set and an associated boost value.

The text in this example is transcribed as Json. I would like this to be transcribed as JSON (all caps)

I have thoroughly read the GCP documentation, but I haven't found a document which relates my problem. I've also tried Azure, where [there's an option to upload a pronunciation file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-and-train#guidelines-to-create-a-pronunciation-file). I'm looking for a similar solution in GCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it myself and got the same results. Even with `maxAlternatives` set to 20.

There is currently no option like a pronunciation file so I have created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185475442) to ask for its implementation.
Remember to star it in order to get an email notification on every update. And, if you can, add your business case and/or impact to give the full picture.

For now, the workaround would be to implement a "catcher" on your code.
In Python, you could use `replace()` or `upper()`.
Something in the line of:

```py
for result in response.results:
    print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript.replace('Json', 'JSON')))
```

And if you need to catch more words, loop over a list with an `if` condition:

```py
result='I need a Json file'
lower_words = ['Json', 'csv']
upper_words = ['JSON', 'CSV']
for result in response.results:
    for lower_word, upper_word in zip(lower_words, upper_words):
        if lower_word in result:
            print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript.replace(lower_word, upper_word)))
```

Of course, this will print at each iteration that meets the condition so in case you could have more then one of these words in a result, you may want to store intermediate result and print after the nested loop.

I hope you won't have too many words to change though or this will slow down your application a lot.